# add class to element - angular 2

Tags: angular

i have this element:

```
   <tabset [pills]="false">
        <tab *ngFor="let event of eventList" title="{{event.name}}" [disabled]="false" >
        Content here

        </tab>
   </tabset>
```

So i want to add the bootstrap class `'nav-justified'` to `<tab>` ,  how can i achieve that? i've tried with `[ngClass]='nav-justified'` and `[class.nav-justified]='true'` and nothing seems to work for me, any thoughts?

thanks in advance

Comment: Should it be there for every tab? If so then just add it normally, class="nav-justified"

Comment: Have you tried `class='nav-justified'` ?

Comment: also your title attr should have [] in order to bind... [title]="event.name"

Comment: @cboston, yes class='nav-justified' doesnt work neither